# Change color of numbers in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I want all the numbers i type in my Java program in Eclipse to be highlighted **red** (because of "Magic numbers" for example) and i looked around in the preferences tab, but i could not find the option to change the color of numbers. How can i do this?

Example:

```
Pane root = new Pane();
    root.setPrefSize(300, 300);
```

300,300 are hardcoded magic numbers and i would like those to be highlighted red.

I explained my problem but stackoverflow says my question doesnt meet the quality standards so im adding this useless extra text so it lets me post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Window>Preferences>Java>Editor>Syntax Coloring>Java>Numbers. Then select whichever color you would like. [here is an image of what the syntax coloring editor looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjlM9.png)